# SQL issue with multiple foreign

Tags: mysql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

## Issue:

*I'm using PostgreSQL Database.*

I have one table (**Albums**) to be linked to two other tables (**Clients**, **Domains**). So if you are Client ***or*** Domain you can have Album. But in Albums table owner can handle only single foreign key. How can I solve this issue?

**Dream**: Single Album can own only (1) Client ***or*** Domain. Need fix issue with foreign keys. Albums: id | owner (multiple foreign -> Clients:id or Domains:id) --> can not do this | name. I just need some smart rework.

### Tables (now can have Album only Domain):

1. Albums
2. Clients
3. Domains

#### Albums (table with foreign key yet):

id | owner (foreign key -> Domains:id) | name

#### Clients:

id | first_name | last_name

#### Domains:

id | owner | name

Comment: Add 2 FK, and a `CHECK` constraint, to enforce only one of them is `NOT NULL`...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto - Ok but Client with id 1 can exist as Domain with id 1 can exist... how can I check if this is Domain or Client as owner

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto - I can add something like ownerType = Client|Domain... but than u can create row with ownerType = Domain and owner with id of client :-D

Comment: Remove the `MySQL` tag....

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 FK columns, and a CHECK constraint, to enforce only one of them is NOT NULL...
Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE albums (
  id        serial PRIMARY KEY,
  client_id integer,
  domain_id integer,
  name      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES clients(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (domain_id) REFERENCES domains(id),
  CHECK ((client_id IS NULL) <> (domain_id IS NULL))
);
```

To query you can use something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, COALESCE(c.id, d.id) AS owner_id, COALESCE(c.name, d.name) AS owner_name,
       a.name AS title
FROM albums a
LEFT JOIN clients c ON a.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN domains d ON a.domain_id = d.id
```

### @e_i_pi's version

```
CREATE TABLE entities (
  id        serial PRIMARY KEY,
  type      integer, -- could be any other type
  -- any other "common" values
);

CREATE TABLE client_entities (
  id        integer PRIMARY KEY, -- at INSERT this comes from table `entities`
  name      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE domain_entities (
  id        integer PRIMARY KEY, -- at INSERT this comes from table `entities`
  name      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE albums (
  id        serial PRIMARY KEY,
  owner_id  integer FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES entities(id), -- maybe NOT NULL?
  name      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
);
```

Query:

```
SELECT a.id, owner_id, COALESCE(c.name, d.name) AS owner_name, a.name AS title
FROM albums a
LEFT JOIN entities e ON a.owner_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN client_entities c ON e.id = c.id AND e.type = 1 -- depending on the type of `type`
LEFT JOIN domain_entities d ON e.id = d.id AND e.type = 2
```

Comment: I just noticed, that the question is `PostgreSQL`, and i gave the answer in `MySQL`... But i do not think too much difference should be there...

Comment: This is an excellent way to create a dynamic relationship that maintains FK constraints. It is possible to take this further, by extracting out to tables like clientEntity, domainEntity, and entityType, and then having the column entityTypeID in albums to assist in applying correct constraints, and also to help the developer select the correct column on the fly.

Comment: Yes, especially when there are more than a few possible "owner" type...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto - If I have Albums like - id | ownerType | ownerId - how can I make constraint to check something like ownerType = Client | ownerId = DomainId === Error

Comment: What @e_i_pi suggests is not like that. I will ad that to the answer....

Comment: @e_i_pi - ok i'm waiting

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto - dude... u forgot get owner_type in your SELECT example... so this is not correct solution... i do not need owner_name... in clients name column does not exist

Comment: @Altaula Owner's type is in the `entities` table, and in the `SELECT` query `e.type` is used. Not forgotten...

Answer (score 0):

Righto, so as suggested in the comment to the answer by @UsagiMiyamoto, there is a way to do this that allows declaration of entity types, with cascading. Note that this solution doesn't support unlimited entity types, as we need to maintain concrete FK constraints. There *is* a way to do this with unlimited entity types, but involves triggers and quite a bit of nastiness.

Here's the easy to understand solution:

```
-- Start with a test schema
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS "entityExample" CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "entityExample";
SET SEARCH_PATH TO "entityExample";

-- We'll need this to enforce constraints
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_entity_type(text, text) returns boolean as $$
SELECT TRUE WHERE $1 = $2
;
$$ language sql;

-- Unique entity types
CREATE TABLE "entityTypes" (
  name          TEXT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT    "entityTypes_ukey" UNIQUE ("name")
);

-- Our client entities
CREATE TABLE clients (
  id                integer PRIMARY KEY,
  name              TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- Our domain entities
CREATE TABLE domains (
  id                integer PRIMARY KEY,
  name              TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- Our overaching entities table, which maintains FK constraints against clients and domains
CREATE TABLE entities (
  id                  serial PRIMARY KEY,
  "entityType"    TEXT NOT NULL,
  "clientID"      INTEGER CHECK (is_entity_type("entityType", 'client')),
  "domainID"      INTEGER CHECK (is_entity_type("entityType", 'domain')),
  CONSTRAINT      "entities_entityType" FOREIGN KEY ("entityType") REFERENCES "entityTypes" (name) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT      "entities_clientID" FOREIGN KEY ("clientID") REFERENCES "clients" (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT      "entities_domainID" FOREIGN KEY ("domainID") REFERENCES "domains" (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

-- Our albums table, which now can have one owner, but of a dynam ic entity type
CREATE TABLE albums (
  id                    serial PRIMARY KEY,
  "ownerEntityID"       integer,
  name                  TEXT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "albums_ownerEntityID" FOREIGN KEY ("ownerEntityID") REFERENCES "entities"("id")
);

-- Put the entity type in
INSERT INTO "entityTypes" ("name") VALUES ('client'), ('domain');

-- Enter our clients and domains
INSERT INTO clients VALUES (1, 'clientA'), (2, 'clientB');
INSERT INTO domains VALUES (50, 'domainA');

-- Make sure the clients and domains are registered as entities
INSERT INTO entities ("entityType", "clientID")
  SELECT
    'client',
    "clients".id
  FROM "clients"
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
;
INSERT INTO entities ("entityType", "domainID")
  SELECT
    'domain',
    "domains".id
  FROM "domains"
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
;
```

If you don't like the idea of inserting twice (once in client, once in entites, for example) you can have a trigger on inserts in the clients table, or alternately create an insert function that inserts to both tables at once.